# CloudFront 404 error on wp-admin and wp-login

Tags: php, wordpress, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to serve my whole site from Cloudfront. I have created a Cloudfront distribution and the frontend is working through a CNAME (blog.mysite.es). I have followed the solution of  [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-login-admin-cookies-problem/#post-7507200) which the author says it worked, but for me is throwing 404 errors like this:

```
   404 Not Found

The server can not find the requested page:

    blog.mysite.es/wp-admin (port 80) 

Please forward this error screen to blog.mysite.es's WebMaster.
```

Does anyone knows about how CloudFront handles this and can help me?

Comment: You might have more luck asking this question on server fault, since this site is more about programming questions, not configuring servers. However, maybe this is your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445396/cloudfront-cname-vs-dns-cname

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is not my case, I have properly configured CNAME. I'll try on serverfault.