# How to check AWS Cloudfront CNAME works?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I had an experience on `cloudflare CDN` by setting the `nameservers`, and I can check by header `CF-Cache-Status: HIT` to see if it works.

But `AWS Cloudfront` setting is in different way and I don't sure whether it works or not.

I've read other stackoverflow posts like [Cloudfront CNAME vs DNS CNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445396/cloudfront-cname-vs-dns-cname), but there have no more details.

---

Lets's say I want to cdn from **domain.com** to **AWS Cloudfront**, and here are what I've done:

1. Request a certificate to **domain.com** from **Certificate Manager**, and add a CNAME record `Name:_5d5g45u2j2r5w1s2a8ed2.domain.com/Value:_5f44y54d25s1de4fg4f52s5s4dc1s5.kdiesksqs.acm-validations.aws` on **domain.com**
2. **Certificate Manager** success validate **domain.com** and the certificate was issued `abcd-1234-abcd-1234-abcde`
3. Create Distribution from **CloudFront** with detail:

   - State:Enabled
   - Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs):domain.com
   - SSL Certificate:domain.com (abcd-1234-abcd-1234-abcde)
   - Domain Name:11ppqrstuv.cloudfront.net

---

When I browse **11ppqrstuv.cloudfront.net**, it looks identically to **domain.com**, so I know AWS is able to grab my file.

> But how could I know the **domain.com** successfully point to **AWS(11ppqrstuv.cloudfront.net)**?

Are there anything I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for many articles, I found my answer, and here is the correct way to set up:

1. Request a certificate to `*.domain.com` from **Certificate Manager**.
2. Go to domain.com Host Server's DNS setting platform(ex: Godaddy's DNS Management) and add the CNAME record(copy from Certificate Manager).

```
    Name:_5d5g45u2j2r5w1s2a8ed2.domain.com
    Value:_5f44y54d25s1de4fg4f52s5s4dc1s5.kdiesksqs.acm-validations.aws
```

3. Wait for **Certificate Manager** validate successfully on `*.domain.com` and generate a certificate `abcd-1234-abcd-1234-abcde`.
4. Create Distribution from CloudFront with detail:

   - State: Enabled
   - Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): `aws.domain.com`
   - SSL Certificate: *.domain.com (abcd-1234-abcd-1234-abcde)
   - other settings may find on AWS CloudFront Developer Guide.
5. Wait for the distribution status show **Deployed**, and it generate a Domain Name: `11ppqrstuv.cloudfront.net`
6. Back to domain.com Host Server's DNS setting platform(ex: Godaddy's DNS Management) and add the CNAME record.

```
    Name: aws.domain.com
    Value: 11ppqrstuv.cloudfront.net
```

7. To test if it works, go to [REDBOT](https://redbot.org), try `http://aws.domain.com/your-folder/file.png`, and you will see something like:

```
    X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
    Via: 1.1 q2ws5d2w8s2sa3as3s2d5ds2ww.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LAX3-C4
    X-Amz-Cf-Id: F1s5s5w5er4f4cls0ekesd4ds5s5sKPoSSCH5e2ss4==
```

8. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a linux machine then you can use **dig** or **host** command in the linux for finding the CName record.

```
dig <your-domain-name>
```

or

```
host -t cname <your-domain-name>
```